# Live noise cancellation of microphone audio with JACK, ALSA, Audacity?

Tags: audio, alsa, jack

Audacity has a very nice noise cancellation filter. Is it possible, using [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/) with ALSA, to pipe live audio through Audacity's noise cancellation filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for real time processing you would want to use [Ardour](http://ardour.org/)

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of Ardour. It looks good. It seems like a suped up Audacity, although I'll certainly still use Audacity for its simplicity and power. thanks

Comment: Doesn't Audacity offer "software playthrough"?

Comment: Where does Ardour have noise-cancellation?

Comment: You can add filters as either pre or post faders (right-click a fader an the top/bottom in the track monitor), they could for example be low-pass or high-pass filters depending on your need, to get rid of "your" noise. In Audacity, first noise is sampled in a quiet section, then this is "subtracted" from your track selection. I didn't think pass-thru is routed through filters, but I may be wrong but this forum probably isn't the correct place to ask.

Comment: Ardour is great but the "Noise Cancellation" plugin (C*Noisegate - Attenuating hum and noise) doesn't seem to work very well. I'd tried various settings and still haven't been able to cut the hissing out. The best thing I've found so far is Audacity's "Noise Removal" effect but that's not real-time. It may help to remember that White Noise is usually 10kHz and up and Line Feed (low hum) is around 50Hz and lower. Attenuating your samples at those freqs will help reduce noise without much loss of quality

Answer (score 2):

I just found http://www.penguinproducer.com/Blog/2012/01/ladspa-noise-removal/
It lists some plugins to use for noise cancellation

basically:
expander->compressor->amplifier->limiter

Works rather well!

Comment: These are Audacity plugins? Where can I download them?

Comment: These are ladspa plugins (unix) - and were already installed on my system - I've been using them in combination with "jack-rack" not audacity.
For audacity, it has a slightly more advanced sampling noise remover - but it is not realtime.

Comment: to add a bit more detail, it seems the Expander and Compressor are the main effective parts - before applying these plugins, I have a constant noisy hiss, after, there is a slight hiss on top of other sounds